# How to make it a function that will export the employees information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

This is a function that imports the employees information from employee management system.I want to make a similar function that can export the employees information.How to make it?

```
def import_employees():
    with open('Employee_database.csv', 'r') as csvfile: #Opens the student answer file, and closes once finished
        employee_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   
        first_row = True
        for row in employee_reader:
            #Skip the first row with column names
            if first_row:
                first_row = False
                continue
            try:
                fullName = row[0] + ' ' + row[1] #Creates full name for dictionary key
                employeeList[fullName] = row
            except IndexError:
                pass
    print('The following employees were imported:\n')
   
    for employee in employeeList.keys():
        print(employee)
    print(' ')
    input('<Press Enter to Continue>')


try:
    import_employees()
except:
    with open('Employee_database.csv', 'w') as employeeCSV:
                employee_writer = csv.writer(employeeCSV)
                csvrow1 = ['FirstName','LastName','SSN','Phone','Email','Salary']
                employee_writer.writerow(csvrow1)
```

Comment: Why do you need to export the file if you don't define a function that modifies the file? In its current state, your program only reads the file if it's there. If not, it creates a file and fills the first row with default data.